# How do I make my TreeCellRenderer fill my JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree, treecellrenderer

How do I make my tree cells fill the width of my JTree:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setCellRenderer(new TreeCellRenderer() { 
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, 
        boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO: How do I make this panel fill the width 
            // of the JTree?
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("ITEM");
            return panel;
        }
});
add(tree);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`, `JPanel` is container,
- empty `JPanel` by default returns `zero Dimension`,
- only empty `JPanel` (AFAIK only) returns `10px` in `BorderLayotu`, in the case that JPanels are placed to the NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, SOUTH areas, then created very nice 10pxs `EmptyBorders`
- have to override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel`, the same ways as is required for Painting in Swing
- no idea for why reason you put `JPanel` as `Renderers JComponent` into `JTree`, maybe there is/are another way(s), sure for better help sooner post an `SSCCE`

Comment: I'm sorry mKorbel, I meant to leave the JPanel blank but there are actually a number of components in it. I just didn't include them in my post - I will make it more clear.

Comment: Renderers Concept is the same for JComboBox, JList, JTable, JTree, return PreferredSize came from JPanel, but your question is about fills available JViewport Dimension???, about fiting JPanel as Renderer to the Rectangle that returns JViewport???

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response; you were correct and setting getPreferredSize worked for me.